# Best way to view and save hd kinect images

Tags: ros, iai-kinect2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the best way to view and save hd images kinect 2?
Driver used is:
https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251279/best-way-to-view-and-save-hd-kinect-images/) by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2017-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [image_view](http://wiki.ros.org/image_view) package has functions to aid in storing images to disk.

If you just want to save single images you can use the image_view node and

> You may save the current image by
> right-clicking on the display window.
> By default, images will be saved as
> frame0000.jpg, frame0001.jpg, ....

for storing all images image_view provides an `image_saver` tool that can be configured to save *all* images, or only to save when a service is called. This allows you to programmatically set what images are stored to disk.

An alternative would be to use [rosbag](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag) to store the image topics and extract them later using [Exporting Image and Video Data](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data). Note that if you are making a rosbag of all topics, including pointcloud data, the bags will become quite large.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0